# duda con colecciones en java pasando parámetros

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo colecciones en java y he visto este programa:

Test.java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    public static void hello(Collection x) {
        System.out.println("Collection");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Testing();
        List x = null;
        t.hello(x);
    }
}
```

Testing.java

```
import java.util.*;
class Testing extends Test {
    public static void hello(List x) {
        System.out.println("List");
    }
}
```

Más allá de que Java Collection es una de las interfaces raíz de Java que maneja  estructuras de datos variables, la siguiente línea de código:

```
public static void hello(Collection x) {
```

está ocupando Collection como se ocupa un atributo int y lo está pasando como parámetro en la función hello();?

Existe un atributo Collection que pueda pasarse como parámetro como se pasa un atributo int?

Answer (score 1):

```
Test t = new Testing();
```

Un objeto **Test** está siendo instanciado con un Objeto **Testing**
, Testing hereda de **Test**.

**Collection** es padre de **List**, entonces **List** es un tipo de **Collection**.

> public static void hello(Collection x) {

**Collection** es el tipo de "dato" de x, por lo que pasa como cualquier otro parámetro.

Normalmente lo has usado como

> public static void hello(String saludo) {

El propósito es el mismo, pasar un Objeto como argumento al método **hello**